# unable to install typescript getting below error

Tags: node.js, npm

When trying to install typescript on the visual studio code I am getting the error below:

```
PS D:\POCProject> npm install -g  typescript
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tarball tarball data for typescript@latest (sha512-7KxJovlYhTX5RaRbUdkAXN1KUZ8PwWlTzQdHV6xNqvuFOs7+WBo10TQUqT19Q/Jz2hk5v9TQDIhyLhhJY4p5AA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tarball tarball data for typescript@latest (sha512-7KxJovlYhTX5RaRbUdkAXN1KUZ8PwWlTzQdHV6xNqvuFOs7+WBo10TQUqT19Q/Jz2hk5v9TQDIhyLhhJY4p5AA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting typescript@latest:
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting typescript@latest:
npm ERR! sha512-7KxJovlYhTX5RaRbUdkAXN1KUZ8PwWlTzQdHV6xNqvuFOs7+WBo10TQUqT19Q/Jz2hk5v9TQDIhyLhhJY4p5AA== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-7KxJovlYhTX5RaRbUdkAXN1KUZ8PwWlTzQdHV6xNqvuFOs7+WBo10TQUqT19Q/Jz2hk5v9TQDIhyLhhJY4p5AA== but got sha512-rbMbvn1PJ65kmCxBiew5UiasJIvzF4yL4i3UhJEctZ62plenABwsF7moaNDyJl5dYRqtjhM6f2TWWDKVysNGPA==. (3228 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     ..\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-08T09_10_03_896Z-debug.log

Note:
node -v
v12.0.0

npm -v
6.9.0

protractor --version
Version 5.4.2
```

I have tried clearing cache and restarting the webdriver-manager but nothing is helping.

Can anyone suggest how else I might try to resolve this?